# Jmeter: how to save both success and failure soap requests values into separate CSV files

Tags: soap, jmeter

I want to run the Jmeter for a soap service and save both success and failed request values into separate csv files. First of all would like to know if this is possible. I am using CSV input file for generating the request. I could see some posts here but I dont know how we can extract multiple specific values from the soap request upon the status of response. As I mentioned I want to do this for both success and failure responses.
Tried adding **XPath2 Extractor** and I could see debug sampler is printing values but not sure how to get them into sepaerate csv files. First of all is that doable ?

[image]

[image]

**Update** I just realized that my original question was wrong. Saving response wont help much to identify the failed records. My idea is to identify both failed and successful records. Need to do some business logic on failed records. Is there anyway I can do that? I would like to get all those fields from CSV file to both success and failed output files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save successful and not successful responses into separate files you can use [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer):

1. For successful responses

   [image]
2. For failures:

   [image]

If the file has to be CSV and you need only variable values I can think of [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer), it doesn't allow you to filter successful and failed responses, however you can add an appropriate column to CSV and filter it later on.

And finally you can just use [Sample Variables property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and variable values will be stored into JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles). It's in CSV format and contains the information regarding whether the request was successful or not and filtering it in [Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent will be quite easy.

Comment: I think I made a grave mistake while posting the question. Just updated.  I want to identify both success and failed requests based on response. I am using csv file to read inputs and wants to create same csv with same values for both failed and success. If not possible at least failed requests.